# Lewis structure of dinitrogen trioxide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, lewis-structure, pnictogen, oxides

I have a confusion related to the structure of $\ce{N2O3}.$ I was taught **1** is the correct one, but I believe **2** is better since it has no formal charge on it. Why is **1** correct and **2** wrong?

[image: Structures of N2O3]

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/72263/what-is-the-criteria-for-determining-structure-of-a-molecule?r=SearchResults ... https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/91233/why-is-the-n-n-bond-length-greater-in-dinitrogen-trioxide-than-in-dinitrogen-tet?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What really happens in nature has higher priority than our believe what happens or should happen. See [Dinitrogen_trioxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinitrogen_trioxide) with the structure, bond lengths and angles.

Be aware both $\ce{NO}$ and $\ce{NO2}$ are radicals with an unpaired electron.

$\ce{N2O3}$ being( $\ce{ON-NO2}$ ) as 2 paired radicals is the direct analogy
to the dimer $\ce{N2O4}$ being $\ce{O2N-NO2}$, both being formed at low temperatures.

Comment: So it’s just what it is?

Comment: @Rasputin Yes, it is what it is. Also keep in mind you're using a model, which is not the same thing as reality. Some times, models do not give the prediction they ought to give.

Answer (score 3):

I think you assume that Nitrogen Sesquioxide is formed by a dehydration reaction of an acid of Nitrogen, hence necessitating the presence of a bridged oxygen. This isn't the case. It is created due to the addition of the radical on the Nitrogen of $\ce{NO}$ to the radical on the Nitrogen on $\ce{NO2}$. Hence why the structure is the way it is.